# Kinect Device not connected

Tags: kinect

I've been trying to get my Kinect connected to my computer. I've installed the drivers and OpenNI, and when I tried to run NiViwer 64, the only message i get is this: "Device: PrimeSense/SensorKinect/5.1.2.1: The Device is not connected!". Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a proper order of installing drivers, sdk etc specially when it comes to OpenNI.
You have to be sure that you didn`t install enything from Microsoft cause it may cause some issues. IMO uninstall everything and go via this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148251/How-to-Successfully-Install-Kinect-on-Windows-Open