# OpenNI does not work with primeSense carmin 1.08x (Kinect) Although OpenNI2 is working with it

Tags: c++, kinect, openni, asus-xtion, primesense

I have the two versions of openNI installed, NI viewer for openNI2.2 works properly with my PrimeSense device, however NI viewer of openNI 1.5.7.10 says primesense/sensorKinect/5.1.2.1: the device is not connected.

This question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533188/kinect-device-not-connected) and the steps of setting up openNI with kinect have lots of tutorials such as [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDuGfAV6hDc) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148251/How-to-Successfully-Install-Kinect-on-Windows-Open).

The problem is all this tutorials are outdated, i followed lots of tutorials and the problem remained, also the links given in them have drivers that does not work (when installed its says install failed).

p.s : i want to use openNI not openNI2 as i want to integrate openCV with openNI using CMake and that can not be done using openNI2.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want us to tell you given the limited information and absence of a [mcve].

Comment: I want to know how can i operate openNI with primeSense given that all the tutorials existing are outdated and having the primeSense driver not working. There is no code involved.